# SQL Server : sp_send_dbmail never queues email when calling stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sp-send-dbmail

I've got a SQL job that is set up to run `sp_send_dbmail` and attach the results of a stored procedure as a csv file to the email. This job was running up until a week and a half ago.

Full disclosure: I made a change to the stored procedure around that time. The stored procedure was previously looking at a table in one linked server and is now looking at a table in another linked server.

I am able to take the code out of the job and run it successfully in a query window, I'm also able to execute the stored procedure successfully in a query window without the `sp_send_dbmail` call.  Additionally, the job executes on schedule and reports success, and I see no error messages in the job history. I've included the code that is in the job to run the procedure and send mail below:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'SMail',
    @recipients = 'xxxx@example.com',
    @query = 'EXEC [REP01].[Mktg_Reporting].[dbo].DailyC2C',
    @subject = 'Daily Call History',
    @query_result_separator=',',
    @query_result_no_padding=1,
    @query_result_header=0,
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
    @exclude_query_output=1,
    @query_attachment_filename='Calls.csv';
```

I didn't change any of this code since I created the job, I only made the change in the stored procedure so that it looked at a different linked data source. Any kind of assistance is appreciated.

Edit: I also checked the `sysmail_mailitems` table and found no messages queued for the current day each time I run the job manually, wanted to make sure I included that detail.

Comment: What is the difference between the two linked servers? Are they both SQL Server, or something else? Are permissions on the linked servers identical?

Comment: The server the job is running on and the linked server are both SQL servers.  I believe the job is being executed by NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM which has the same permissions on both servers.

Comment: Just checked again after my original reply, the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user did not in fact have the proper permissions on the linked server.  Thanks for pointing me that way!

Answer (score 0):

I just looked a little bit deeper into this, Pondlife was on the right track regarding a permissions issue.  I looked a bit deeper after my initial reply to him and realized that the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM user was not set up to properly access the linked server.  I've since fixed the problem.